# mypy: Why is "int" a subtype of "float"?

Tags: python, mypy

Why does "mypy" consider "int" as a subtype of "float"? A subtype shall support all methods of its supertype, but "float" has methods, which "int" does not support:

test.py:

```
def f(x : float) -> bool:
    return x.is_integer()

print(f(123.0))
print(f(123))
```

The static type checker accepts passing an "int" argument for a "float" parameter:

```
(3.8.1) myhost% mypy test.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

But this does not guarantee, that there are no errors at runtime:

```
(3.8.1) myhost% python test.py
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(f(123))
  File "test.py", line 2, in f
    return x.is_integer()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'is_integer'
```

because "float" has additional methods, which "int" does not have.

Comment: Oh wow, this seems bad to me, here's the explanation: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/duck_type_compatibility.html

Comment: I believe the reason they consider it an **int** a subtype of **float** is because an **int** can fit inside a float memory-wise

Comment: @BlackFrog no, it cannot.

Comment: @BlackFrog An `int` *can't* fit in a float. Python `int`s are not machine `int`s. (Anyway, I'm not sure how that would be relevant to type checking, which isn't really concerned with run-time representations of types.)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the rationale for using duck typing with `int` and `float` seems to completely ignore the fact that both types have methods, or at least methods other than `__add__` et al.

Comment: @chepner I think so, this looks like a real bug to me. mypy is still in very active development, so it's probably worth opening an issue.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Python is rather mathematical, and ℤ⊂ℝ⊂ℂ. Looks good to me.

Comment: @StefanPochmann yes, but as shown here, from a type system POV, it is not

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the link about duck type compatibility of int and float and your view, that this looks like a bug in mypy.

Comment: @chepner yes I agree, the duck typing reasoning seems to ignore some methods.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Just saying it makes sense. I think it's not a bug, it's a feature. Anyway, see https://github.com/python/typing/issues/48 including Guido's reply.

Comment: It's a compromise, to be sure, though one that could be improved.

Comment: @StefanPochmann thanks for finding that, I was looking for some relevant issue in github. Note, though, Guido even says (maybe a bug?) when referencing the similar issue with the `.hex` method. Although, I think in that context it means `int.hex` should be implemented, and indeed, `int.is_integer` could be too. Honestly, that would be the best solution to me.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga are you suggesting all `int` and `float` methods/attributes should be the same just to resolve this mypy issue? I count 25 additional methods `len(set(dir(int)).symmetric_difference(dir(float)))`

Comment: @Chris_Rands no, only the public methods in `set(dir(float)).difference(dir(int))` should be implemented on `int`, if an `int` is acceptable anywhere a float is (not vice versa)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, so just 'hex', 'as_integer_ratio', 'fromhex', 'is_integer'

Comment: Ints now have .as_integer_ratio and .as_integer methods, leaving only the specialized .hex and .from_hex as float-only.

Answer (score 5):

'Why does "mypy" consider "int" as a subtype of "float"?'

Because practicality has so far been considered to beat purity here.  This is not to say that one could not propose that typing define a Scalar type that would include ints and floats but only be valid for arithmetic operations.

Note that int / int was changed in 3.0 so that float(int / int) == float(int) / float(int), to make int and float arithmetic consistent for equal int and float values.

Note also that a type-check passing does not mean no runtime errors: division by zero and overflow are still possible, as well as many others.

UPDATE: as of Python 3.8, ints now have an .as_integer_ratio method, and as of 3.12, ints will gain an .is_integer method, leaving only the specialized .hex and .from_hex as float-only.

Comment: Static type checking typically is supposed to prevent crashes and runtime errors for types known at compile time. I mean that is the purpose. So it seems, with this decision, mypy did not understand the complete meaning of static type checking.

Comment: @ChrisoLosoph See update above.

Answer (score -2):

As **@juanpa.arrivillaga** pointed out, the explanation is on https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/duck_type_compatibility.html.

> A subtype shall support all methods of its supertype, but "float" has methods, which "int" does not support

`int` is **not** a subtype of `float`, so it doesn't have to support methods of `float`.

The mechanism is good because passing integer values shouldn't cause errors, unless you really want them as in your example. You explicitly tried to use a method which doesn't exist. In common situations, we only make arithmetic operations on numbers, so a problem rarely exists and you can always avoid it by adding `.0` as you wrote.

It is a common behavior in most languages to assume that `int` is a special case of `float`, consider for example C++ `int` to `float` implicit conversion.

Comment: Honestly, saying "you can always avoid it by using the correct type" is not a convincing argument to me for a type checker being wrong.

Comment: The whole *point* of static typing is precisely to *avoid* using a method that isn't defined for the type. The first part of the answer is fine; going on to explain why there isn't a downside is just doing everyone a disservice.