# mypy fails to detect errors when Callable return type is bool/numeric

Tags: python, mypy

The following file, test.py, has multiple type errors due to return types of Callable's not matching.

```py
from typing import Callable


def func() -> bool:
    return True


f1: Callable[[], bool] = func   # okay
f2: Callable[[], float] = func  # should be error: f2's return type does not match func's

r1: float = f1()                # should be error: r1's type float does not match f1's return type bool
r2: float = func()              # should be error: r2's type float does not match func's return type bool
r3: float = f2()                # okay, given how f2 is declared
```

Yet mypy reports no errors:

```sh
$ mypy test.py --check-untyped-defs
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Bizarrely, errors *are* detected if the return type of `func` is `str` instead of `bool`:

```py
from typing import Callable


def func() -> str:
    return 'abc'


f1: Callable[[], str] = func    # okay
f2: Callable[[], float] = func  # mypy error, line 9

r1: float = f1()                # mypy error, line 11
r2: float = func()              # mypy error, line 12
r3: float = f2()                # okay, given how f2 is declared
```

```sh
$ mypy test.py --check-untyped-defs
test.py:9: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Callable[[], str]", variable has type "Callable[[], float]")
test.py:11: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "float")
test.py:12: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "float")
Found 3 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

This is Python 3.7.5. Am I mistaken in thinking mypy should catch the errors no matter the return type? Or is it doing some sort of silent type coercion between bools and numeric types?

Comment: Unfortunately, support for `Callable` hints being checked seems weak. I use them as documentation, but I've been continually disappointed by what dumb mistakes it allows through.

Comment: Note too though that `x: float = True` also doesn't raise a warning. Perhaps due to the fact that bools are a numeric type? Idk.

Comment: Sorry to spam comments, but this might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59619778/mypy-why-is-int-a-subtype-of-float) too.

Comment: For some reason I thought Python 2 implemented bool as int, but Python 3 made it its own type. For example, if you test `False is 0` and `True is 1`, they both are false (although `False == 0` and `True == 1` I think are both true). Guess I was mistaken.