# Mypy fails to find a type error in simple one line function

Tags: type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I have written a very simple Python module with self-inconsistent type hints, and still mypy finds no errors.
Here is the module

```py
def func(x: int) -> float:
    return x
```

and here is a complete terminal session illustrating the unexpected behavior:

```
~/src$ mkdir temp
~/src$ cd temp
~/src/temp$ echo -e "def func(x: int) -> float:\n    return x"
def func(x: int) -> float:
    return x
~/src/temp$ echo -e "def func(x: int) -> float:\n    return x" > mymodule.py
~/src/temp$ mkvirtualenv temp
created virtual environment CPython3.9.7.final.0-64 in 99ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/danielsank/.virtualenvs/temp, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/danielsank/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==20.3.4, pkg_resources==0.0.0, setuptools==44.1.1, wheel==0.34.2
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/danielsank/.virtualenvs/temp/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/danielsank/.virtualenvs/temp/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/danielsank/.virtualenvs/temp/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/danielsank/.virtualenvs/temp/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/danielsank/.virtualenvs/temp/bin/get_env_details
(temp) ~/src/temp$ pip install mypy
Collecting mypy
  Using cached mypy-0.910-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (23.2 MB)
Collecting toml
  Using cached toml-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting mypy-extensions<0.5.0,>=0.4.3
  Using cached mypy_extensions-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.5 kB)
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.7.4
  Using cached typing_extensions-3.10.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Installing collected packages: typing-extensions, toml, mypy-extensions, mypy
Successfully installed mypy-0.910 mypy-extensions-0.4.3 toml-0.10.2 typing-extensions-3.10.0.2
(temp) ~/src/temp$ mypy mymodule.py 
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Why doesn't mypy notice that `func`'s type hints are inconsistent with its code?

Comment: There is no type inconsistency here. [For static typing, ``int`` is considered a subtype of ``float``.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-numeric-tower).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mypy: Why is "int" a subtype of "float"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59619778/mypy-why-is-int-a-subtype-of-float)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yep, that answers my question.